# Dispatch Tables vs Switch Statements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how dispatch tables are an advantage over switch statements, let say we have the following two scenario to handle the same functionality

**Switch statement**

```
swtich(value){
   case 'a':
     fun1(value);
     break;

   case 'b':
     fun2(value);
     break;

   case 'c':
     fun3(value);
     break;

}
```

Now the above switch statements can keep growing and can become disorganized, hence there is an alternative with "dispatch tables" where we can makes use of an object

**Dispatch Table**

```
function dispatching(value){
    var list = {
       'a': fun1,
       'b': fun2,
       'c': fun3
    }

   return list[value]();
}
```

If i we are to follow the above function, wouldn't the Object **list** have to go through all its properties when invoked. I see how its makes it maintainable but does it improve in performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...but does it improve in performance?

The odds of it mattering are extremely, extremely small. If it may matter for what you're doing, the best thing to do is code it both ways with representative options, and test it, for instance with http://jsperf.com.

But yes, looking up a property on an object is likely to be faster than the equivalent `switch`. To process a `switch`, the engine is required to test the cases in source-code order and stop at the first match; JavaScript `switch` is really just another form of `if...else if...`. (Of course, if the engine can see that the options are mutually-exclusive, it can optimize that process.) In contrast, modern JavaScript engines are just-in-time compilers and produce classes at runtime; property lookup by string name (`list[value]`) isn't as fast as property lookup by name literal (`list.a`), but it's still really fast, since the engine doesn't have to proceed sequentially and can look up the property using a balanced hash tree or similar.

Arguing the other way, however: If your functions are fairly short, the engine may be able to inline them in the `switch` version (e.g., under the covers, move the function code into the `switch` rather than actually making a function call), which could take it the other way in terms of performance. It depends a lot on what your functions are doing.

But again, the odds of it mattering are very low. This isn't going to be the bottleneck in your app. I'd make my decision based on which I felt was more maintainable in context, and worry about performance if and when I identified the dispatch mechanism being the chokepoint. (That's never happened for me yet. :-) )

Comment: Thank You @T.J. Crowder for the detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance comparison at http://jsperf.com/dispatch-table-vs-switch. They are very similar in terms of performance.  I think using switch statements or dispatch tables is just based on coding preference.

One real world data point is the Facebook Reactjs library which tends to care about maintainability and performance, generally prefers switch statements in their action dispatchers.

Comment: The test you've linked to is testing the best possible scenario for `switch`: The first `case`.

Comment: There are couple of different revisions of the test case available and you can edit it any way you want to test different things.  For the vast majority of real world cases, the performance is going to be very similar.  If you have 20000 items (like in http://jsperf.com/dispatch-table-vs-switch/5) you will probably want to use a dispatch table, otherwise, either is fine.

Comment: I looked at all of them before commenting, they all have issues. Fundamentally, synthentic tests like that are rarely indicative of real-world performance, not least because the functions they dispatch to can be inlined fairly readily (which biases toward the `switch`), whereas that may or may not be true of the real-world functions. But we completely agree, I think, that performance really isn't the main decider here anyway. :-)